# kendo UI Gantt chart in angular: to implement a chart where in the second pane I require only weekdays starting letters

Tags: kendo-ui, gantt-chart, angular14, kendo-gantt

[here I don't require the first row, I just require the weekdays from M T W TH F excluding dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17tZv.png)

below I am attaching a snapshot of the design that I need to implement
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mcyry.png)

looking for code so that I can customize according to my requirement.

```
                          <kendo-gantt
                          [style.height.px]="500"
                          [kendoGanttHierarchyBinding]="ganttChartData"
                          kendoGanttExpandable
                          [initiallyExpanded]="true"
                          [filterable]="true"
                          [sortable]="true"
                          [columnMenu]="true"
                          [columnsResizable]="true"
                          [columnsReorderable]="true"
                      >
                          <kendo-gantt-column
                              field="title"
                              title="Node"
                              [width]="60"
                              [expandable]="true"
                          >
                          </kendo-gantt-column>

                              <kendo-gantt-column
                                  field="node"
                                  title="Activity Id"
                                  format="dd-MMM-yyyy"
                                  [width]="60"
                                  filter="date"
                              > </kendo-gantt-column>

                          <kendo-gantt-timeline-week-view [width]="200" >
                           
                          </kendo-gantt-timeline-week-view>

                      </kendo-gantt>
```

this is the html code I have used and below I am attaching the editor url https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jpk6jf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhierarchical-data.ts
application url :https://angular-jpk6jf.stackblitz.io, please generate a code as per the UX provided above based on weeks.